# URLs with .jsf extension still redirect to .xhtml after FacesServlet removal from web.xml

Tags: jsf, glassfish, facesservlet

I have a web application that originally was a JSF app, but has been migrated to pure HTML/JavaScript. We are now in the progress of eliminating JSF completely.

We had the physical file main.xhtml, which was requested by "main.jsf", where the FacesServlet was declared in web.xml with url-mapping *.jsf.

We have moved the content to main.html, and put a meta-tag REFRESH in main.xhtml to redirect to main.html.

Now the problem is that even if I remove FacesServlet from web.xml, it still redirects the request for main.jsf to main.xhtml. If I rename the file main.xhtml to main.jsf, requesting main.jsf gives a 404, and the server log says it cannot find a file "main.jsp".

Now the question is: If it redirects *.jsf to *.jsp or *.xhtml even when there is no FacesServlet in web.xml, what is responsible for this redirections?

I'm using GlassFish 3.1.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using JSF 2.0+ on a Servlet 3.0+ container, and there's no explicit `FacesServlet` registration in webapp's own `web.xml`, then the `FacesServlet` will during webapp's startup automatically be registered on URL patterns `/faces/*`, `*.faces` and `*.jsf`.

See also its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html):

> This servlet must automatically be mapped if it is not explicitly mapped in `web.xml` or `web-fragment.xml` and one or more of the following conditions are `true`.
>
> - A `faces-config.xml` file is found in `WEB-INF`
> - A `faces-config.xml` file is found in the `META-INF` directory of a jar in the application's classpath.
> - A filename ending in `.faces-config.xml` is found in the `META-INF` directory of a jar in the application's classpath.
> - The `javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES` context param is declared in `web.xml` or `web-fragment.xml`.
> - The `Set` of classes passed to the `onStartup()` method of the `ServletContainerInitializer` implementation is not empty.
>
> If the runtime determines that the servlet must be automatically mapped, it must be mapped to the following `<url-pattern>` entries.
>
> - `/faces`
> - `*.jsf`
> - `*.faces`

JSF 2.3 will add `*.xhtml` URL pattern to the set (which is backported in Mojarra 2.2.11).

If you want to stop this behavior, and you can't eliminate the triggers (e.g. still having a `faces-config.xml`), then your best bet is to explicitly register `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml` in webapp's own `web.xml`. This will override the default auto registered URL patterns.